# Splitting a string that contains unicode characters \xe2\x80\xa9 does not actually split anything

Tags: java, regex, string, unicode, split

I have a string in java:

> String something = "The aim of this study is to evaluate epidemiological and clinical impact of tumor disease in an Italian renal transplant waiting list and to propose a screening schedule for neoplastic detection.\xe2\x80\xa9 We retrospectively observed data of patients enrolled on the Emilia-Romagna kidney transplant waiting list between 1st August 2008 and 31st December 2010, evaluating the different causes of getting out from the list, the histologic type and incidence of cancer and the correlation between cancer onset\t\t\t\t\t\t10543566";

However, when I do :

```
String temp[] =  string_something.split("\t\t\t\t\t\t");
```

I only get one element in the new array when I am supposed to get 2, so:

> temp = ["The aim of this study is to evaluate epidemiological and clinical impact of tumor disease in an Italian renal transplant waiting list and to propose a screening schedule for neoplastic detection.\xe2\x80\xa9 We retrospectively observed data of patients enrolled on the Emilia-Romagna kidney transplant waiting list between 1st August 2008 and 31st December 2010, evaluating the different causes of getting out from the list, the histologic type and incidence of cancer and the correlation between cancer onset\t\t\t\t\t\t10543566"]

when it should be

> temp = ["The aim of this study is to evaluate epidemiological and clinical impact of tumor disease in an Italian renal transplant waiting list and to propose a screening schedule for neoplastic detection.\xe2\x80\xa9 We retrospectively observed data of patients enrolled on the Emilia-Romagna kidney transplant waiting list between 1st August 2008 and 31st December 2010, evaluating the different causes of getting out from the list, the histologic type and incidence of cancer and the correlation between cancer onset", "10543566"]

How could I fix this?

Comment: After removing the illegal-in-Java escape sequences "\xe2\x80\xa9", I get two elements as expected.

Comment: Your String is either broken, or you are not posting your actual String.

Comment: Still, tab char is a legal regex literal, something java should translate during its string interpolation.

Comment: Can you provide your actual situation that isn't working? I feel like I've messed up your post so if we can get this solved, I will make sure no information got lost by my editing.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but you need to match the literal string `\t\t\t\t\t\t`, right?  Have you tried splitting on `\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t`?

Comment: @CAustin As we already [tested](https://ideone.com/9aDkzZ) `split("\t\t\t\t\t\t")` gives same results as `split("\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t")`. That is because Java's regex engine translates `"\\t"` to `"\t"`, and it also accepts `"\t"` literals, so results are the same.

Comment: I have no problems splitting this in Perl using your strings.

Comment: @CAustin - If trying to match a literal `\t`, you'd need a stringed regex `"\\\\t"`

Comment: So, it looks like these chars are causing a problem `ΓÇ⌐` eh?

Comment: Does java support c-lang types ? Usually strings consist of type `char` which is signed 8 bit. Maybe unsigned char type will help. Does java support that?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel The string I provided is the thing that isn't working, what other information do you think would be helpful, I am not sure what else to provide. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to match a literal string in Java use:

```
\Q ... \E
```

Or simply:

```
 Pattern.quote(string)
```

This might work:

```
String temp[] =  string_something.split("\\Q" + "\t\t\t\t\t\t" + "\\E");
```